Are there any programs/libraries that can generate all acyclic digraphs on n vertices?
Are there any programs/libraries that can generate all unlabeled acyclic digraphs on n vertices?
I'm thinking of something like Nauty's geng; but for DAGs.
(I have seen posts describing general approaches. Has anybody implemented an algorithm and released it as a library or stand-alone program?)

Do you have some specific application or use case in mind for such a thing?

Does this answer your query? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13546785

At a quick glance, I think that will work.  I don't have a highly specific use case yet.  Just poking around thinking about possible interesting connections between diagraphs and boolean circuits.
